# Removing Html Tags from Woocommerece Rest API description

Tags: xamarin.forms, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to remove the Html tags from the response on the Woocom Rest API Like the `<p>` From below

```
"description": <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

What i've tried so far

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
function rei_woocommerce_short_description($the_excerpt) {

    return wp_strip_all_tags($the_excerpt);
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute', 'woocommerce_attribute_filter_callback', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_attribute_filter_callback( $formatted_values, $attribute, $values ) {
    return wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) );
}
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'rei_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1);
add_filter('woocommerce_description', 'rei_woocommerce_description',10, 1);
```

I'm building the application in Xamarin however I do believe this is resolved on the site it self.

Comment: If you're building in Xamarin, then all you have to do is once you get the message back just use the .Replace method that strings have. So it would be like description.Replace("<p>","")

Comment: This is Definitely a solution Thank you! I will ask however id love to do this on the site as my Fetch Method is getting enormous  I have so many checks currently happening, And am already facing crashes, However if this is the only way Ima go ahead with it

Comment: So i've never used that API and I assume the reason it has the <p> tag is so that it could just be pasted into the DOM. I am a bit confused since you do mention your site (which i assume is different than your Xamarin app)

Comment: So Its just a Wordpress site they build that has a Ecom Plugin we use for the clients big Market day where they have around 300 Suppliers and 50k+ people who shop there they wanted a app that can do what the website can do So the api Response looks like this http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product, If you dont mind me asking why would the tag be needed for the Dom? id like to understand the root as to why this is the way it is

Comment: That's a good question, could be an oversight on their end. So since it is from the API what I would say is create some sort of class in your Xamarin that makes the API requests, and in that class it can handle the result, this way the filtering logic is in your Xamarin code behind, you can create a class to represent the data the API calls back, and then use things like LINQ, etc. to filter and select the data you need

Comment: Also another great Suggestion. Im using a Wrapper to handle the Request Filtering Logic I had issue's with deserializing I just dint have the time to resolve and the wrapper resolved it for me, I find LinQ absolutely terrifying but I will look into maybe creating my own class that Inherits from the wrapper then filter and Replace all the HTML tags then send them back to the Wrapper Class before the Call Request So maybe have that happen before the page loads then run the request method and lessen the Thread strain I hope

Comment: For API related  serialization and deserialization i normally use Newtonsoft, if you don't have then you can easily install it using the nuget manager

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, I appreciate the suggestions and will definitely give them a go.

Comment: you're very welcome